# Update Raspbian O

Tags: update

I'm trying to update my RPi but keep giving me an error:

> failed to fetch some archives maybe run apt-get update or try with ..fix.missing?

But the problem is when I run `apt-get update` still nothing changes.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: If possible the exact apt-get commands you're running and the output from them could be useful for finding a solution.

Comment: We really can't help you unless we have the exact command you are running and the output from that (the entire thing, including all errors). If you would include those it would help us resolve your issue faster and better.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `sudo apt-get update`.

Your OS could also be out of date and need an upgrade. Try `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your problem is that you do not have an internet connection. Try running `ping www.google.com` and see if that works, or if you cannot do that.

Comment: never too late to check the basics :)

Comment: yeah lol i spent 2 weeks with this same issue, until I realized that I needed a static IP to get the internet working with a bridged connection. If this does happen to be the authors problem, http://www.suntimebox.com/raspberry-pi-tutorial-course/week-3/day-5/ worked great for me

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `apt-get update -f` to fix this error.

and you could also make a habit of updating through the `raspi-config` utility, apparently  it handles more updates than just the apt-get.